# How to have all jobs of a build be executed exclusively on the same node?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins server with half a dozen builds. Each of these builds is composed of a parent job that triggers anywhere between 4 and 6 smaller jobs that run in parallel. I use the EC2 plugin to keep the number of active slaves in line with the number of queued builds. Or in other words, slaves are coming and going all the time. Each slave has 7 executors (parent job + max(4, 6)).

It is absolutely crucial that all jobs of a build are executed on the same machine. I also cannot allow any jobs from build A to execute on a machine that has jobs from build B running.

What I'm looking for is a way that prevents Jenkins from using any inactive executors of a node as long as any jobs from a previous build are still active on it.

I've spent the day experimenting with a combination of the Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin and the NodeLabel Parameter Plugin. Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug somewhere that causes throttled builds to not contribute to the Load Statistics of a slave. This in turn means that throttled build will never trigger Jenkins to spin up additional slaves. Obviously this is totally unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use "This build is parameterized"
and pass the $NODE_NAME as a parameter between the builds and then use it at the "Restrict where this project can be run"

Comment: that is a great idea. I've tried this earlier today but kept running into the following problem: let's say there are 2 parent jobs queued, causing the EC2 plugin to spin up 2 new slaves. Unfortunately when the first of these slaves has finished spinning up, Jenkins sees there are now 7 free executors and immediately moves both parent jobs to the first and second executor of this slave. I need to avoid this.